# Can't import pictures in Reactjs using require()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Here's the thing, when i opened my react project all the images stopped appearing, this happened all of a sudden as it was working a couple of hours ago. This seems to be an issue with the way they're being imported, the method i've always used is `src={require(./Picture)}`, i have also tried with `const logo = require('logo')  src={logo}` and `import logo from './logo.png'` with the only one working is the last mentioned.

While debbuging that, every google aimed that the problem was with a dependecy called webpack, which i tried to remove and reinstall it, also installing an older version, but nothing worked.

Any idea of what could have caused it?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `create-react-app` and `require` to import your images, `require` returns an ES module instead of a string. It's because in `file-loader` the `esModule` option is enabled by default.

Just make sure, you import your images in one of these ways:

```js
const image = require('../path/to/image.jpg').default;
// OR
import image from '../path/to/image.jpg';
```

So

- `src={require(./Picture)}` should be `src={require(./Picture).default}`
- `const logo = require('logo')` should be `const logo = require('logo').default`
- `import logo from './logo.png'` should just work

Comment: This worked totally fine, many thanks. Why did the `.default` became necesarry all of a sudden tho?, a couple of hours ago it was working absolutely fine without it

Comment: If you haven't updated your dependencies that's really strange. Not sure what's changed.